# \printbibliography[heading=none] with apacite

Tags: bibliographies

I want to hide the title of the bibliography, which is usually done by using 
`\printbibliography[heading=none]` command instead of `\bibliography`, but the command is undefined in `apacite` package. Are there any nice workarounds, that hide the section title and hide the entry from the TOC?

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your settings?

Comment: `\printbibliography[heading=none]` is a `biblatex` command, you cannot use it with any other package.

Comment: @karlkoeller  i use the standard article template with \usepackage{apacite} ... but anyway, the question has been answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apacite` redefines the standard definition of the environment `thebibliography`. I think you can do the same as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\let\st@rtbibsection\@bibnewpage
\let\st@rtbibchapter\@bibnewpage
\makeatother
```

Comment: Just to play it safe, you may want to add a comment that these instructions should be inserted *after* the `apacite` package has been loaded.